# I wanted to create the array below, but for some reason it gives an error.The array itself was created using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I have an **array (numpy)** but an error is generated when I run the program itself

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
Input_data = np.array([2.1, -1.9, 5.5],[-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],[0.5, -7.9, 5.6],[5.9, 2.3, -5.8])
data_binarized = preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=0.5).transform(input_data
)
print("\nBinarized data:\n", data_binarized)
```

**error:**

```
TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I've tried removing the square brackets and rearranging them, but to no avail.

Comment: Look again at the error.  Which line?  We think it's the `np.array(...)`; you didn't create the array.  Count the arguments to that function (the lists), and compare that to what `np.array` documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it like this:

```
np.array([[2.1, -1.9, 5.5],[-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],[0.5, -7.9, 5.6],[5.9, 2.3, -5.8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The array data needs to be 'array-like', so you have to put it into a list like the other comment suggests. Here's the link to the numpy documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html.

In general,

```
arr = np.array([x1, x2, x3, ..., xn])
```

Above, x1 are lists in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue while trying:

```
mymatrix = np.array(mylist, mylist, mylist)
```

Finally square brackets helped. Rookie mistakes :)

```
mymatrix = np.array([mylist, mylist, mylist])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_data = np.array([[2.1, -1.9, 5.5], [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],[0.5, -7.9, 5.6], [5.9, 2.3, -5.8]])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Exact duplicate of the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816563/12846804 - without the explanations